# Cpanel deleted subdomain now shows 500 error

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, http-code-500

I created a subdomain in cpanel and then decided that I actually didn't need it, so I deleted it using cpanel.

Now when I navigate to that subdomain in my browser I get a 500 server error. If I try any other random subdomain, they redirect to the root.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get rid of the 500 error?

Comment: cPanel should have a place to look at the error log. Can go and look there and see if there are any errors that correspond to when you try and look at that subdomain.

Comment: Hi Paul, I should have also explained - it was showing this error 'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.' now I'm not getting any errors in cPanel.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting Apache, it seems like a setting has been changed but not refreshed.